# C: defining function below main - why does this compile?

Tags: c

```
struct ack {
    char a, b, c;
};

main()
{
   struct ack bad;

   foo(bad);
}

foo(c)
   struct ack c;
{

}
```

This is a test case in gcc. When I try to compile it using gcc4.8, it compiles without problem. However, I have learned that you have to declare your functions before **main**. Why does this even compile?

Comment: You don't *have* to in C89, but it's highly recommended to do it.

Comment: I urge you to ditch this completely outdated C syntax.  Unless you are going to be maintaining critical code that is older than 20 years, there is no reason not to learn modern C syntax.

Comment: "I urge you to ditch this completely outdated C syntax" Did you even read the text? "This is a test case in gcc." "This is a test case in gcc. " "This is a test case in gcc."

Comment: https://github.com/mirrors/gcc/blob/gcc-4_8-branch/gcc/testsuite/gcc.c-torture/unsorted/BUG24.c

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try to compile with

```
-std=c11 -pedantic-errors
```

and you'll get the required diagnostics.

By default `gcc` compiles with `-std=gnu89` which is c89 + GNU extensions. The c89 rule for implicit declarations has been removed in c99.

Comment: But why is it accepted when compiling without any specific paramteres?

Comment: @klaufir Because by default C89 rules are used.

Answer (score 0):

Currently, in general, when the compiler finds the call to `foo(bad)` in `main()` and foo is NOT defined, then the compiler assumes it exists and will return `int`.

This punts the problem to the linker who will complain if `foo()` is NOT defined somewhere in the source file.